# How to sort column that combines of letters and numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL Server table that contains a column which contains values mixed of letters and numbers like this "u-340","u42/43","u-44","u-540" and it shows up in this order when I make a select query order by its name.

When my query is `Select Name from table1 order by Name`, it shows up in this order

1. u-340
2. u42/43
3. u-44
4. u-540

How can I make it show up like this

1. u42/43
2. u-44
3. u-340
4. u-540

Comment: With difficulty. If you want to values to treated like numbers, they should be in a different column, in a strongly typed numerical data type

Comment: Suppose the data was `{ 'u-1', 'u-2/u-4', 'u-3' }`. How would you want that to sort?

Comment: it will not be like this but always the number after the "/" sign is the next number. so it will be { 'u-1', 'u-2/u-3', 'u-4' }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way. I notice that sometimes your data start swith `u-`, and other times it starts with just `u`. It seems like that's deliberate because you have it in your question twice, so this answer assumes it is. If it's not, then let me know and the answer can be simplified.

I have used a little "trick" with sign because I expect it's faster than another nested call to `replace`, but performance is never going to be great if you have to sort on a calculation.

I also don't know how big your numbers can get, so for the purpose of this answer I have allowed for up-to-8-digit numbers.

```sql
select      table1.*
from        table1
cross apply (select cast(replace(replace(name, 'u', ''), '/', '.') as decimal(16,8))) t(v)
order by    t.v * sign(t.v)
```

Or with `abs` (faster than `sign`? Probably)

```sql
select      *
from        t
order by    abs(cast(replace(replace(name, 'u', ''), '/', '.') as decimal(16,8)))
```

Comment: but only one problem occurs when I try it with another table that have same values like mentioned above plus strings without numbers! then i have an error of failed converting data type nvarchar to numeric. So to be simplified if we assumed that the data is {"u-340","u42/43","u-44","u-540","hello","Brown"}. then i get failed error conversion from nvarchar to numeric

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible way you can use. It's not clear from your data but I don't think your values are either signed or an expression, it *looks* like you just want to sort by the first numeric value found in the string?

If so you just need to extract this and use it in an ordering criteria.

One way to do so doesn't rely on knowing the non-numeric values that might need replacing so you can use this for strings containing any characters

```
select name
from table1 t
cross apply (values(Stuff(name,1,PatIndex('%[0-9]%',name)-1,'')))s(v)
order by Try_Cast(Left(v,IsNull(NullIf(PatIndex('%[^0-9]%',v)-1,-1),10)) as int)
```

Comment: It worked perfect too sir, thank you so much

Comment: but only one problem occurs when is use "distinct" it gives me this error "ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified." do you have any idea pls why is this happening